# Grids can be curvy. How long is yours?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, geometry, grid, graph-theory

Consider depicting a [simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleCurve.html), [open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedCurve.html), two-dimensional curve on a W wide by H high grid of text where `X` represents part of the curve and `.` represents empty space and no other characters are used.

Every grid space has 8 neighboring grid spaces, its [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood). Grid spaces beyond the borders are considered empty.

A grid contains a *curve* if it has exactly one `X` *OR* if it has more than one `X` where:

- Exactly two `X`s have only one neighboring `X`. These are the curve's endpoints.
- Every `X` besides the endpoints neighbors exactly two `X`s. These form the bulk of the curve.

> For example, this grid where W = 9 and H = 4 contains a curve:
>
> ```
> ....X....
> .X.X.X.X.
> X..X..X.X
> .XX.....X
> ```
>
> Likewise, these grids (W = 4, H = 3) have curves:
>
> ```
> ....  .X..  ....  ....  .X.X
> ....  X..X  ..X.  XX..  X.X.
> ..X.  .XX.  .X..  ....  ....
> ```
>
> These grids, however, do not contain a curve:
>
> ```
> ....  .XX.  ...X  XX..  ....  X.X.
> ....  X..X  ..XX  XX..  .X.X  .X..
> ....  .XX.  .X..  ....  ...X  X.X.
> ```

We can find the length of a curve by summing the distances between all neighboring pairs of `X`s:

- The distance between two orthogonally neighboring `X`s is 1 unit.

  ```
  XX
  ```

  ```
  X
  X
  ```
- The distance between two diagonally neighboring `X`s is [√2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2) units.

  ```
  X.
  .X
  ```

  ```
  .X
  X.
  ```

> For example, the length of the curve in the grid
>
> ```
> XXX.
> ...X
> ..X.
> ```
>
> can be visualized as
>
> [image: length example]
>
> so we can see it is 1 + 1 + √2 + √2 = 4.828427...

The length of a curve with only one `X` is zero.

When a grid does not form a curve its length is not well defined.

## Challenge

**Given a grid of text of `X`s and `.`s, output the length of the curve it contains, or else output something such as `-1` or `Null` to indicate the grid has no curve.**

For input you may use other characters than `X` and `.` if desired, and H and W may be taken as input if needed. Input as a nested list or matrix filled with 1s and 0s instead of a string is also fine.

You may output a float for the curve length or alternatively two integers A and B where `length = A + B*√2`.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

## Test Cases

```
XXX.
...X
..X.
2 + 2*√2 = 4.828427...

....X....
.X.X.X.X.
X..X..X.X
.XX.....X
3 + 8*√2 = 14.313708...

....
....
..X.
0 + 0*√2 = 0

.X..
X..X
.XX.
1 + 3*√2 = 5.242640...

....
..X.
.X..
0 + 1*√2 = 1.414213...

....
XX..
....
1 + 0*√2 = 1

.X.X
X.X.
....
0 + 3*√2 = 4.242640...

....
....
....
....
-1

.XX.
X..X
.XX.
-1

...X
..XX
.X..
-1

....
.X.X
...X
-1

X.X.
.X..
X.X.
-1
```

Comment: I recommend allowing the solver to choose their output format for grids that have no curves (any consistent value that's not of the form m + n*sqrt(2) for any m,n≥0).

Comment: @Greg Sounds fine. Done

Comment: `[x.x,...,.x.]` isn't a valid curve, right?

Comment: @carusocomputing correct

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
t2Y6~Z+*ssGt3Y6Z+*tt1=z2=wssGzqE=*Gz1=+?}_q]ssy-h2/
```

Input is a matrix of zeros and ones.

Output is `B`, then `A`. Non-curves give a negative `A`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19iFGlWF6WtVVzsXmIcaQZklZQY2lYZ2ZYDRaoKXW213KsMbbXta@MLY4uLK3UzjPT//482UIBAQyhtYA1hI2FrQyQVYDGwGrgOkEgsAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S4jw@l9iFGlWF6WtVVzsVWIcaQZklZQY2lYZ2ZYDRaoKXW21vKoMbbXta@MLY4uLK3UzjPT/u4T8jzZUAEEDawUDMDSEMIAisVzRBjBBKG1gDWEjYWtDJBVgMbAauA6QCMIkawUUBswWsGqYSdYKUAPQtUFdCVaGLAe1DW423EhDa7grUeSwOQWLAYYQw3E4Ch5QhlgdBXcBLAwA).

#### Explanation

**Computing the length of the curve** uses two 2D convolutions<sup>1</sup>: one with the Moore mask, and another with a mask containing only the diagonal neighbours. The results are two matrices with the same size of the input, which will be denoted as *M* and *D* respectively. *M* gives the total number of neighbours for each point, whereas *D* gives the number of diagonal neighbours.

The results in *M* and *D* must be filtered to discard points that don't belong to the curve. Also, they must be divided by 2, because "being neighbour of" is a a symmetric relation, so each point in the curve is counted twice.

**Determining if the curve is valid** is more cumbersome than I expected. To do this, the code tests three conditions:

1. Does the number of ones in *M* equal `2`? (That is, are thre exactly two points with a single neighbour?)
2. Does the total sum of *M* equal the number of points in the input curve times `2` minus `2`? (Together with condition 1, this tests if all non-zero values in *M* except two of them equal `2`)
3. Does the input curve contain a single point?

The curve is valid if conditions 1 and 2 are true, or if condition 3 is.

```
t       % Implicit input matrix of zeros and ones. Duplicate
2Y6~    % Push [1 0 1; 0 0 0; 1 0 1]
Z+      % 2D convolution, keeping size
*       % Multiply to zero out results for non-curve points. Gives matrix D
ss      % Sum of matrix D
Gt      % Push input again wtice
3Y6     % Push [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]
Z+      % 2D convolution, keeping size
*       % Multiply to zero out results for non-curve points. Gives matrix M
tt      % Duplicate twice
1=z     % Number of ones
2=      % Does it equal 2? This is condition 1
wss     % Swap. Sum of matrix
G       % Push input again
zqE     % Number of nonzeros values minus 1, and then multiplied by 2
=       % Are they equal? This is condition 2
*       % Multiply. This is a logical AND of conditions 1 and 2
G       % Push input again
z1=     % Does it contain exactly one nonzero value? This is condition 3
+       % Add. This is a logical OR with condition 3
?}      % If result was false
  _q    %   Negate and subtract 1. This makes sure we get a negative value
]       % End
ss      % Sum of matrix M
y       % Duplicate sum of matrix D from below
-       % Subtract
h       % Concatenate horizontally
2/      % Divide by 2. Implicitly display
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [Convolution is the key to success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>316</s> <s>315</s> 311 bytes

I think this covers all cases; at least [the test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#nVLLbsJADLzzFdvbOjjtmmOj9MIfcLV8QCypFkqCEhAIVf11upuFkEqtCJUVxZnM@DHy2S4LVWiLM5zC60g1ebPfZDZnI4mejieACbPBpEYjRVWrWrlSWcHuf1blKaFBytY5M2ufA2r/DcIuWbUiF0SVCukqpq5QluuxE16MVzIvrXKfkbsIhHpevi99qfRrCl3XGziDqPdqkeyQ8/FlEmjHQNvMt7rBk9vqpNFrZAEAqWq/hJFsW7typ/mAKQk3@gBPeaN9cmrbnOJykJLnfyxLvWvhXYDX8ryo9l5M8DYRGHmLmDCECW5gCLpkAZNRcDUUsRBf3jKIushueTFaHeGPx2PUY1FXn266FhvQqZvQDJ6QLmzqbUZDN@t1wa7WMB11na/Y/TnpMic9oPvdl8c6078dul0KPexQ/xbuX0D/bq7T/qk4n78B) work.

Also, there surely is still a lot to golf down, probably in the beginning where the edge cases are handled.

```python
def f(d,R,C):
 s=sum;d=[0]*(C+2),*[[0,*r,0]for r in d],[0]*(C+2);o=-1,0,1;k=[[[(1,0),(0,1)][i*j]for i in o for j in o if d[r+i][c+j]and i|j]for c in range(1,-~C)for r in range(1,-~R)if d[r][c]];w=[x/2for x in map(s,zip(*s(k,[])))]or[0,0];print([w,-1][s(w)!=s([s(z)for z in d])-1or[len(t)for t in k].count(1)>2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#RY9BboQwDEX3PUW6sxnTAsuidMMNZmt5gQhUgQ6ghBEjVPXqNAFpuvv5fi@Wd9N2qgNDV6rw40V57e@30mjOJIHqUiAlzBkljjLpJqecsqMyQs95Oek0p4zyctDMDCEjQXijsE36Q7JRmlSM/Rltpwy7ixVuLr3Uo1H252SbCLh6/GrDV@lvhc@t/@UVTz/YIuWq@fFeROwRsVs9g6fNzpB4GIgFEWVy4YhMytnZcQFeKc2FPaz4qj2EsB1rtvM4TPPAf7cjLEe9xHqQt2a6BznHz0Jw3/8A)

How it works:

1. `d,R,C` are 1. a list of lists with 1 as curve and 0 as background, 2. row and column count
2. Insert a row of 0's before and after and a column of 0's before and after `d` so we don't have to worry about the edge of the 2d array
3. For every 1 in the 2d array, scan the neighbourhood for 1's and add (1,0) to a list if the relation is diagonal, else add (0,1)
4. Sum all tuples, so that (n,m) represents the number of diagonal and non-diagonal neighbours, respectively
5. Check if the number of relations is exactly the number of 1's minus one; if not, not a curve.

Thanks to @Helka Homba for pointing out a missing case.
Thanks to @TuukkaX and @Trelzevir for the golfing tips.

Comment: Looks like `d=[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]` will fail here (added testcase).

Comment: @HelkaHomba You're right, I oversaw that. Thanks!Fixed it (now unfortunately with more bytes).

Comment: `s=sum` saves 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>153</s> 150 bytes

```
Switch[Sort[Join@@BlockMap[If[#[[2,2]]<1,Nothing,Tr[Tr/@#]]&,#~ArrayPad~1,{3,3},1]],{1},0,{2,2,3...},1/.#~ComponentMeasurements~"PolygonalLength",_,]&
```

Takes a 2D array, with `0`s for `.`s and `1`s for `X`s. Outputs `Null` for non-curves.

```
1/.#~ComponentMeasurements~"PolygonalLength"&
```

Mathematica has a 45-byte built-in for this, but it outputs some numbers for non-curves and 1/sqrt(2) for input `{{1}}`. Correcting these cost 105 bytes (could be golfed?).